# GemFire put on server Region using JAVA

Tags: java, gemfire, in-memory-data-grid, bigdata

How can I connect to GemFire cluster with java code , get regions and put some values into this regions from client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several examples of what you're trying to achieve within the Official User Guide, specifically in [Client/Server Example Configurations](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/geode/topologies_and_comm/cs_configuration/client_server_example_configurations.html). A minimalist example below.

**server-cache.xml**

```
<cache>
    <cache-server/>
    <region name="TEST">
        <region-attributes refid="REPLICATE"/>
    </region>
</cache>
```

**client-cache.xml**

```
<client-cache>
    <pool name="default">
        <locator host="localhost" port="10334"/>
    </pool>
    <region name="TEST" refid="PROXY"/>
</client-cache>
```

**ClientApp.java**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ClientCache cache = new ClientCacheFactory().set("cache-xml-file", "client-cache.xml").set("log-level", "config").create();
    Region region = cache.getRegion("TEST");
    region.put("key1", new MyPojo("attribute1", "attribute2"));
    cache.close();
    System.exit(0);
}
```

You might want to check the [spring-data-gemfire](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-gemfire/) project, and get rid of all the boilerplate :-).
Cheers.